# CORS issue with google cloud Python Flask API

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, flask, cors, google-cloud-storage

I have CORS troubles calling my API hosted on Google Cloud from another domain

This is the error I get:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapi.app/ask_question' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' (or 'https://mywebsite.dev') has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Here is the code (hosted on https://mywebsite.dev) calling my API:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface ChatMessage {
  text: string;
  isUserMessage: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatbot',
  templateUrl: './chatbot.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatbot.component.css']
})
export class ChatbotComponent {
  isChatbotCollapsed = false;
  userInput: string = '';
  chatMessages: ChatMessage[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  sendMessage() {
    const userMessage = this.userInput;

    this.chatMessages.push({ text: userMessage, isUserMessage: true });

    const apiUrl = 'https://myapi.app/ask_question';
    //const apiUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/ask_question';
    const payload = { input: userMessage };

    this.http.post(apiUrl, payload).subscribe(response => {
      const apiResponse = response as { output: string };
      const botResponse = apiResponse.output;

      this.chatMessages.push({ text: botResponse, isUserMessage: false });
    });

    this.userInput = '';
  }
}
```

Here is the code (hosted on https://myapi.app) of my API:

```
import json
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins":"https://mywebsite.dev"}})


@app.route('/ask_question', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def ask_question():
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        response = make_response()
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mywebsite.dev')
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
        return response
    data = request.get_json()
    input_string = data['input']    
    output = 'hello, you said' + input_string
    
    response = make_response({'output': output})
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://mywebsite.dev')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong ?

I tried to add my domains explicitly with:
`CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})`
or
`CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": ["https://mywebsite.dev/", "https://mywebsite.firebaseapp.com/"]}})`

I tried to add headers to the response with:

```
@app.after_request
def add_cors_headers(response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://mywebsite.dev'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
    return response
```

I tried to add an environment variable for CORS in google cloud

None of this worked

Comment: 1) You almost always want `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS`. Your code is not handling the HTTP method `OPTIONS`. 2) Where is the client code running and where is it downloaded from (the website URL)? That is the `origin`. Your CORS allowed origin is `https://mywebsite.dev`. That means the web browser must be downloading the code from that origin. I think your problem is that you do not understand what `origin` means and what `cross-origin` means and how a browser determines that a request can be made (first OPTIONS, then POST).

Comment: 1) Is the wrong indent for `return response` a typo for myapi.app source code? 2) You are returning three CORS headers. Change all of them to return `*` (the wildcard). Does everything work? If not, then something else is wrong. If yes, then modify one header at a time to figure out which one is the problem. Start with the `Origin` header. Then `Methods` and finally the `Headers`. 3) For the most part, you do not care about anything besides `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. The other two can be wildcards.

Comment: 1) I am assuming that `this.http.post` is not adding authorization. That code is not shown.  2) I am also assuming that you are running the client code in a web browser loaded from   `mywebsite.dev`.3) Remove all the comments about localhost, postman, etc. They only cloud your question and are not part of a solution. The only items that matter are the request, where the request comes from, where the request goes to and the response.

Comment: yes it was a typo error, the indent is correct in my code, you assume right there is no authorization added, yes with chrome; I Try these changes

Comment: I still have the same error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapi.app/ask_question' from origin 'https://mywebsite.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Modifications: ... CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}) ...
    response = make_response()
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  ...
  response = make_response({'output': output})
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Comment: Add the log entry from Cloud Run Logging showing the request and the response. I think you have a different problem that appears to be a CORS issue but is not.

Comment: It looks like it ' something else with gunicorn, here is the OPTION 503 error: {
  "textPayload": "The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#malformed-response-or-connection-error",
  "insertId": "649b60c7000e1cd665e313f7",
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "OPTIONS",
    "...
  }

Comment: I forgot to add the flask_cors in my requirements

Comment: I addes flask_cors to my requirements.txt and it works, Thanks a lot @JohnHanley

Answer (score 0):

The error seemed to be coming from the way I configured the CORS response header but it was because I forgot to add flask_cors==4.0.0 in my requirements. I added it and it works

In the browser all what we could see was a CORS error, I tried to be specific by adding headers with the exact origin and the OPTION and POST methods but I still had the same error, I tried be more generic by replacing the origin with "*" but I still had the same error:

myapi.app/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapi.app/ask_question' from origin 'https://mywebsite.dev' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

By checking the cloud run log entries I saw that there was two types of error, one 503 on the OPTION about CORS and another type:

from flask_cors import CORS.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'"

Thank you @JohnHanley for your comments

Comment: Add details on how you determined the problem and the solution such as the Cloud Run log entries. Since Cloud Run was actually returning an HTTP error (503) and your code does not return the CORS headers for the HTTP response on error, the browser said CORS error when the actual problem was not a CORS issue. That means you should add code to your app that handles HTTP errors and adds the CORS headers. That way the client can receive the actual HTTP error instead of seeing a CORS error.